# linear-gradient not working correctly when using px

Tags: ios, css, pixate

I have the following css class:

```
.bookshelf-view
{
    background-color:linear-gradient(to bottom, #c7c8cd 0px, #eaeaec 20px, #abaeb3 21px, #f9f9fa 30, #ffffff 100%) no-repeat;
}
```

which I apply to a `UIView`. It works great when I use only `%` as measurement unit, but repeats everything (as if I used `repeat-y`) if I try to use `px` as measurement unit. Is there a way to make this combination work (px + %)?

Answer (score 1):

gradient are `background-image` , not `background-color`.

`30` is not a valid value , it's missing a unit , either `px` , `%` , ...

test this :

```
.bookshelf-view
{
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #c7c8cd 0px, #eaeaec 20px, #abaeb3 21px, #f9f9fa 30px, #ffffff 100%) no-repeat;
}
```

[example with background-image without background-position](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/liGDx/)